# SELinuxs policy.conf configuration

Tags: selinux

I'm trying to configure SELinux on my home pc. During installation /etc/selinux/policy file had not been created thus I was not able to configure custom policy with checkpolicy. So I've copied it from an example. Here it is:

```
SELINUX=permissive 
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
SETLOCALDEFS=0
REQUIREUSERS=0
AUTORELABEL=1
```

Configuration itself seems extremely simple, yet when I try

```
checkpolicy
```

I get an error

```
policy.conf:1:ERROR 'syntax error' at token 'SELINUX' on line 1:
```

How can this be fixed? I feel like the whole idea of adding this file manually is wrong.

selinux version is 0.5.6

uname says:

```
Linux debian 4.9.0-8-amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

policy file that is loaded into the kernel is located at

/etc/selinux/<'SELINUXTYPE'>/policy/policy.<'version'>.

Where <'SELINUXTYPE'> is the policy name specified in the SELinux configuration file /etc/selinux/config and <'version'> is the SELinux policy version.

An example /etc/selinux/config file is shown below where the SELINUXTYPE=targeted entry identifies the policy name that will be used to locate and load the active policy:

```
SELINUX=permissive
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

From the above example, the actual binary policy file would be located at /etc/selinux/targeted/policy and be called policy.29 (as version 29 is supported by F-20):

```
/etc/selinux/targeted/policy/policy.29
```

Comment: yep, I have exact same file apart from three lines and it does not work :( Removing these lines does not fix anything